# Intent for video recording gives error

Tags: android, camera

I want to record a video from my Android application.
like this

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + app.getBaseName());
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
    }



    filename = "Video" + lastfile() + ".mp4";

    File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + app.getBaseName(), filename);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 222);
```

and in Activity on result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 222) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Return to back 222" + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Return to back");


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }

        Log.v("log_tag", "Return to back fury");
    }

    finish();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

using this, camera is starting then I clicked middle button for recording start than I clicked left side button to stop and save and application crashed.

I printed value of resultCode in onActivityResult which gave me 0.
and video was saved on my given path with given name properly.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not found proper solution for this but I solved my problem using this flow. let save video file anywhere by default and make another copy where you want, you can also delete original file after copy.

like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == 222) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){   
   try {
     AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
     FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
     File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + app.getBaseName(), filename);
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }       
     fis.close();
     fos.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO: handle error
   }
  }
 }
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The resultCode 0 correspond to RESULT_CANCEL if i am not wrong but why do you have a "finish();" at the end of the onActivityResult? You should remove it.

Comment: Thanks Damien, Yes I removed it still crash, no error in log-cat. an also video is saving at proper location. than why it crashes I can't understand.